# Flex Datagrid Sort

Tags: apache-flex

The default behavior of the Flex datagrid descending sort is that a selected row remains in view, meaning that the view will scroll down to show the selected row.  I would like to change this so that when doing a descending sort the veiw remains at the top, with the selected row staying in the same position with a different row.  I have tried different variations with this code but cant' get it to work:

```
var index:int = new int(myDG.selectedIndex);
var vertPos:int = myDG.grid.verticalScrollPosition;

myDG.selectedIndex = index; 
myDG.grid.verticalScrollPosition = vertPos;
```

Thanks for your help.  I am just beginning with Flex.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is the following:

Lets define `newIndex` as the desired index you want your datagrid to navigate to.

You could try something like this:

```
dgInstance.scrollToIndex(newIndex);
dgInstance.selectedIndex  = newIndex;
```

The thing is that I didn't test the code so it might be necessary to add a:

```
dgInstance.validateNow();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Where would this code go?  In a sortCompareFunction?  Could you give me an example?  In an AdvancedDataGrid it seems the firstVisibleItem could be used to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I think you could add the code in a sortCompareFunction, but I'm sure it can go in a normal method too. I've had some time ago a requirement in a project that required the piece of code that I've added in my answer. Based on your last sentence, are you using now an advdg or a dg?